# Can you make Mac remember password for appleid?

Tags: macos

My macbook pro keeps forgetting the apple id password all the time and asks me to reenter it. This happens way to often. Something like once in every two days.

Can Mac not remember the password once it has been entered?

Comment: The OS sometimes asks you to type your AppleID password as a security measure. Automatically filling it in would essentially bypass the security, giving anyone with physical access to your Mac access to your entire AppleID.

Comment: I guess you are right.